# Load Foundation modal on page load

Tags: jquery, prototypejs, zurb-foundation

I'm having a bit of an issue. I want a modal dialog to pop up on page load (ideally only the first time a person visits a page, but I know nothing about cookies and will perhaps look into that later). I'm using zurb's foundation, jquery, AND prototype (essentially because I'm too lazy to write a non-prototype-reliant contact form).

My issue is this: I want to be able to have a foundation modal dialog appear on page load. I tried a few things, to no avail:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#introModal').reveal();
});
```

Then realized that I had placed jquery in no conflict mode to allow prototype to work, and changed it to

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($){
    $('#introModal').reveal();
});
```

Still to no avail. 
The site in question is [basstv.net](http://basstv.net). Any ideas?

Answer (score 5):

for foundation 4

```
 $("#myModal").foundation('reveal', 'open');
```

Comment: You just need to place the code in $(document).ready(function() function

Answer (score 0):

The conflict with jquery is the "$" sign, try it like this

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
  jQuery("#introdModal").reveal();
});
```

Notice that i use jQuery in front instead of the statements.

Hope it helps

Comment: Sorry, I tried that as well and get an "object has no method 'reveal'" error.

Comment: @Salem, the new error tells you everything you need to know. There is no "reveal" method.

Comment: I'm following the foundation documentation: http://foundation.zurb.com/docs/reveal.php
I'd dig through their js, but it's all minified and almost impossible to read.

Comment: @Salem make sure that the lib has been correctly loaded, also you can load the uncompressed lib from their website for dev purposes, after that you can go http://jscompress.com/ <- there to minify and gzip the library.

Comment: @Salem another suggestion is to use the console from a google chrome or the console from the firebug addon in mozilla for testing, write jQuery("#introdModal").reveal(); in the console, see what the error tells you, also remove jquery no conflict before developing any type of script in jQuery, it may screw up your test environment.

Comment: Thank you, I appreciate it. I haven't had much experience with debugging  Javascript, so your instructions are quite helpful.